# How do you parse a JSON array of objects?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Can anyone tell me how to parse arrays of arrays of object in flutter? When I am parsing the json I am getting error as `type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>.`

I'm trying to get the data from the API to be displayed on the screen, to later on build a GridView to display all the products & their respective prices.

I copied majority of the code from the flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

This is the link to the API: https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/jewelery

I'm a student & trying to learn as much as I can so please be very specific where possible :) thanks

code:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';


class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Accra Thrift"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff00eaff),
        ),
        body: new Center(

          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('${snapshot.data!.title}');
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ));
    // ),


  }
}

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/jewelery'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final double price;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({
    required this.price,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      price: json['price'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the JSON structure in the link you provided, it's clear that it is a list of maps, not just one map. Each map in the list corresponds to one instance of `Album`. This means you aren't just fetching one album in your API call, so you cant deal with the response like it's one Album. You need to return a `List<Album>`, for instance:

```
Future<List<Album>> fetchAlbums() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/jewelery'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    dynamic data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return data.map((element) => Album.fromJson(element)).toList();
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I understand what you mean by this & I'm trying to use it but I still don't know how to implement it across the rest of the code. I'm trying to get it to display all the information inside the list on the screen, but I'm getting an error in this line of code `if (snapshot.hasData) { return Text('${snapshot.data!.title}'); }` , which I'm guessing is because I need to write some code to be able to parse through the elements of the list. Could you help with that?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? If `snapshot.data` is now a `List`, then it won't have the getter `title`. You'll probably want to return a `ListView.builder()` or something similar from your `FutureBuilder`. That way it will be easy to iterate by passing in an index like this `snapshot.data.toList()[0].title`.

Comment: I've finally been able to get it to work. To answer your question, I was getting the error _The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'List<Album>'_, but it is no longer an issue. I decided to return a `GridView.builder()` from my `FutureBuilder` & was getting the error _type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Album>>'_, so I decided to change `List<Album>` across the file to `List<dynamic>` & it is now behaving how I want it to. Thanks!